# Visual studio 2015 crashes when I stop debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Have you encountered this problem where your visual studio 2015 crashes after stopping debugging mode ? I tried a lot of solutions like:

- Creating new settings in NVidia drivers to render my visual studio app to high resolution
- Uninstall and install the visual studio with some errors of packages of sp3
- Repair it multiple times

and after trying a lot of work around I'm still getting the same problem. after running my program it runs smoothly but when I tried to stop the debugger my visual studio crashes and reboot it to start page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this kind of problem.
You have to check if you installed the right ***Microsoft visual studio redistributable***. In my case I have installed the

- **Microsoft visual studio redistributable (64x)2015-2019**
- **Microsoft visual studio redistributable (84x)2015-2019**

To solved the problem I uninstalled those two versions after uninstalling I look for my visual studio 2015 and click modify after that, I repair the application and automatically it will install the right redistributable for vs 2015 and will took some time for the repair. After the repair my visual studio is now running smoothly